# Outlook 2010 Add-in throws error message

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, outlook, vsto

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and am trying to create an Outlook 2010 Add-in, and found an MSDN article on how to set up a rudimentary add-in at this url: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx.  So far my code is exactly like in the article, no changes at all, and when I try to run in debug mode I get the following error:

> Outlook experienced a serious problem with the add-in.  If you have
>   seen this message multiple times, you should disable this add-in and
>   check to see if an update is available. Do you want to disable this
>   add-in?

Here is a copy of the code in the ThisAddIn.cs file:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector +=
            new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        if (mailItem != null)
        {
            if (mailItem.EntryID == null)
            {
                mailItem.Subject = "Added Text";
                mailItem.Body = "Added Text to Body";
            }
        }
    }

    #region VSTO generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InternalStartup()
    {
        this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
        this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

I've been searching for posts on this problem, but have had no luck, can anyone help with this?

Comment: Don't you just love a generic message like that?  Here's what I'd do to get started on this  1) Determine if outlook is even able to get into the add-in at all.  You can put in Trace.WriteLine statments on entry and exit for each method.  This will tell you if it even get's into the add-in.  Then if it does get in you will need to find out how far in it gets.  Just put in more trace points.  If MSFT doesn't even call the add-in then it's an outlook related issue.  Unfortunate, many of us are NOT outlook internals experts. But WINDBG will show you the exception. Problem is you have to know it.

Comment: Can you actually step through your code? This error can be displayed if you terminated Outlook while it was calling into your addin.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko, no I am not able to step through the code.  I close Outlook, hit F5 in Visual Studio and Outlook starts to re-open and then immediately pops up a dialog box with the add-in error.  I can't get it to hit a break point in Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you check if your dll is loaded using Process Explorer from SysInternals? Are you sure you do not have any unresolved dependencies that would prevent your dll from being loaded? Anything in the Output log in VS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Microsoft's EMET version 4.0 was causing this problem. The solution turned out to be disable the "Export Address Table Filtering" for Outlook in EMET, or to upgrade EMET to EMET version 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in the code you have provided. So there are few suggestions that you should try.

Clean your solution and run Outlook separately, Outlook should give no warning.

Make sure your project properties have `Code optimization` disabled, Target platform is `AnyCPU`and Debug info is fully generated.

Rebuild solution and start debugging after putting one breakpoint at

`private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)`

and another at

`void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)`

While debugging an Add-in, never stop debugging from VS, close outlook properly to stop debugging.

So does it now hits the breakpoint?

Comment: Sorry to take so long to respond to your post, we were out on our winter shutdown, and I didn't see this until now.  I followed the steps you outlined above very carefully, and still get the same error message.

Comment: Disable all other addin for a while and give a try to debug by stepping in using F11, look where it goes. Do not stepover any statement.

Comment: My apologies again for taking so long to reply.  I just tried your suggestion to disable all add-ins and step in with F11, and still get the same exact result.